# Automatically copying a file to a network drive when it is saved

Tags: applescript, osx-mountain-lion, automator

I was wondering if there is any way through applescript or automator in Mac OSX Mountain Lion to automatically copy a file or folder to a network drive after the file is saved/the folder is modified. I am trying to do this for a user who designs in Photoshop and has 2GB+ size files that take a long time to save to the network drive directly so I am trying to create a way where he can save locally and automatically have it copied over to the networked drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using launchd, you could save a plist like this as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/rsync_folder.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>rsync_folder</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>bash</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>[[ -e /Volumes/WD ]] &amp;&amp; rsync -a ~/Notes /Volumes/WD</string>
  </array>
  <key>WatchPaths</key>
  <array>
    <string>~/Notes/</string>
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then load it with `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/rsync_folder.plist` or by logging out and back in.

Or create a rule like this in [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php):

[image]

Neither watches for changes to files in subfolders (like ~/Notes/subfolder/file.txt) though.

Comment: I found it easier to just write a two line bash script that uses the at command to schedule a copying of the folders every so often.